# Getting 404 page not found after adding ContextLoaderListener to spring mvc project with primefaces pages

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, primefaces

I am new to Spring and trying to make integration between spring and primefaces. I am getting 404 page no found when I run the project on tomcat after adding the `ContextLoaderListener` and `RequestContextListener`.
My web.xml file:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
   <web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
            xmlns:web = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
            xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
            http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
            id = "WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    
    <welcome-file-list>
      <welcome-file>login.xhtml</welcome-file>
   </welcome-file-list>
    
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
      <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
      <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
   </servlet-mapping>
     
     <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
         <param-value>
            /WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml
        </param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>
            org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
    
    <listener>
    <listener-class>
        org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
    </listener-class>
  </listener>
    
</web-app>
```

and this is my faces-config.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_3.xsd"
    version="2.3">
 
    <application>
     <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
   </application>

     <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>/login.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
    </navigation-rule>
    <navigation-rule>
        <display-name>/login.xhtml</display-name>
        <from-view-id>/login.xhtml</from-view-id>
        <navigation-case>
            <from-outcome>viewRecords</from-outcome>
            <to-view-id>view.xhtml</to-view-id>
            <redirect/>
        </navigation-case>
    </navigation-rule>
</faces-config>
```

and following is my controller class:

```
    package com.testtask.nagarro.controller;

    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import javax.annotation.Resource;
    import javax.validation.Valid;

    import org.hibernate.annotations.Source;
    import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.validation.BindingResult;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

    import com.testtask.nagarro.forms.LoginForm;
    import com.testtask.nagarro.forms.StatementForm;
    import com.testtask.nagarro.interfaces.StatementRepository;
    import com.testtask.nagarro.interfaces.UserService;
    import com.testtask.nagarro.models.Statement;

    @Controller
    public class NagarroController {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    
    public UserService getUserService() {
        return userService;
    }

    public void setUserService(UserService userService) {
        this.userService = userService;
    }

    @RequestMapping(value= "/", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String loginPage() {
        
        return "login";
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/login", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public ModelAndView login() {
        
        ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
        model.setViewName("login");
        
        return model;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value="/viewRecords", method = RequestMethod.POST) 
    public String showHomePage(StatementForm form) {
        
        System.out.println("In view records controller");
        
        List<Statement> records = getUserService().getRecordsByAccountId(form.getAccountId());
        
        return "view";
    }

    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST)
    public String processForm(@Valid LoginForm loginForm, BindingResult result, 
                                                    Map<String, LoginForm> model) {
        String username = "UserName";
        String password = "password";
        
        if(result.hasErrors()) {
            
            return "loginform";
        }
        
        loginForm = (LoginForm) model.get("loginForm");
        if(!loginForm.getUsername().equals(username) || !loginForm.getPassword().equals(password)) {
            return "loginForm";
        }
        
        model.put("loginForm", loginForm);
        return "home";
        
    }
    

}
```

I tried to find a solution online but I am confused because most of the examples are using jsps.
please point me to the problem, I am attaching the github link.

Comment: This is the repo of the project: https://github.com/tabusharkh/nagarro

Answer (score 0):

Your views are NOT in webapp/WEB-INF folder as you defined in your InternalViewResolver bean.
They are located in webapp folder.

Comment: Should it be in the WEB-INF folder? in my dispatcher-servlet I am adding the '/webapp/' as the prefix of the InternalResourceViewResolver

Comment: You are not using dispatcher-servlet.xml, you defined (with a typo ) that you are using your spring.xml in your web.xml file
Btw it should be 

      /WEB-INF/spring.xml
not

      /WEB-INF/spring/spring.xml

Comment: Also, I found that you even have commented out spring boot main method in your project, considering typos and bad structure, I would suggest you, as friendly advice, start small, make sure that you can run your views and stop getting 404, after that, you can pile up services, models, repos etc, since this project is clearly the product of following advice from 3 different guys at the same time. Start small, then build up and scale.

Comment: Here is a nice example with good structure
https://crunchify.com/simplest-spring-mvc-hello-world-example-tutorial-spring-model-view-controller-tips/

Comment: I updated the repo. removed the dispatcher-servlet.xml file and moved the jsf files to the view folder as the configuration in spring.xml file. But, still getting the same problem. I want to say that I am getting an exception when I run the project on a server, the exception is: Error creating bean with name 'nagarroController': Injection of autowired dependencies failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException:.... if this could be the problem I can edit the post and post the stacktrace